# Is there ambiguity in this sentence?

Tags: word-order, ambiguity

> **Further to fathom** Aquinas on this matter, however, it is useful to remember that, when he explains what goodness is, he typically says that to be good is, quite generally, the same as being desirable. (On Evil, introduction, by Brian Davies)

I think there is ambiguity in this sentence. I can understand "further" to mean "furthermore". Also "further" can be seen as tightly following "fathom". More probably, I think the author means **"to fathom further..."**. If so, I think the word order better remains to be "to fathom further.."

Comment: I read it as `Furthermore, to fathom Aquinas on this matter, it is useful to remember..`. It looks like an editing error to me where both `further[more]` and `however` remained where one should have been chosen,

Comment: Yes, it looks like it should be _To further fathom_. It is a clumsy sentence however you look at it though.

Comment: It would be _[For `indef`] to remember [that ... Aquinas₁ typically says [that ... desirable]] is useful in order [for `indef`] to fathom Aquinas₁ further [than some previous standard]_, except that some rules (like extraposition, adverb fronting, indefinite subject deletion, pronominalization, and _in order_ deletion) have applied. Probably ill-advisedly.

Comment: + What James Webster, terdon, and John Lawler have said; and I think this is a misuse of *fathom* - *plumb* would be better.

Comment: I suspect the author didn't write *to further fathom* because he had been instructed that one should not split infinitives. I think it's ambiguous, and could mean either *furthermore, to fathom* or *to further fathom.* This sentence shows why splitting infinitives is a useful grammatical construction in English.

Comment: Please provide a link to the source of this quotation, specifically so that we can read what came previously, in order to understand the "Further" & "however".

Comment: After looking at the previous few sentences, I think further here is a misplaced adverb (= more deeply) rather than an augmentive sentence connector (= in addition).

Comment: I think "Further" should have a comma after it.  I'm more comfortable with "furthermore," but perhaps when Davies wrote the original sentence, "further" was more commonly used.

Comment: I agree with Edwin Ashworth that Davies means that the way to plumb deeper into the question is to see the meaning of goodness for Acquinas, in comparison with the preceding attempt to give instances of goodness, like success or achievement. I think Davies might thought that to fathom further is more neutral than to plumb deeper into, and it sounds more analytical and scholarly prudent.

Comment: The foregoing sentences are: Yet how we are to understand the word good in this context? As we have seen, Aquinas associates goodness with success or achievement. And he certainly wants to say that when seeking what we take to be good we are trying to succeed or achieve in some way. Further to fathom...

Answer (score 1):

There's no ambiguity, it's not an editing error, further should not be replaced by furthermore, and it's not a misuse of the verb fathom. Apart from that, the comments above were quite accurate.

Yes, the sentence structure is a little strange. "Further to fathom" just means "In order to comprehend more deeply".

Comment: I quite agree. The adverb placement is not very felicitous, but there is only ambiguity in the sentence if we start assuming editorial errors and such things. As it stands, the opening words can only be understood to mean “to further fathom”.

Comment: I think that what gives so many readers a sense of unease about this sentence is the accumulation of dross it contains—everything from the opening seven-word preamble to the eminently dispensable "it is useful to remember that" to the gratuitously mismatched parallelism of "to be good" and "being desirable." Does the original 35-word sentence say anything of substance that the following 14-word sentence omits? I don't think so. "Nevertheless, in explaining what goodness is, he generally equates being good with being desirable."